# I was wondering if mojo can be used to optimize importing >1,000,000 csv files into Python using Mojo?

Tags: caching, memoization, mojo

We have loaders in our Django app and I think we can make it faster by using caching and memoization, but I was wondering if mojo can make it even faster and if so can someone give me an example. Here's the header for the mvr.csv.
first,last,address,city,state,zip,lat,long,make,model,body,veh_yr,expires,color,plate_no,decal_no,phone.

standard loading protocol